# What is the translation for 以后还得了?

Tags: translation, expressions, sentence

So I came across seeing this post and I find that I can't translate "以后还得了" to English.

But based on my knowledge, this post is saying that her daughter would be very clever if she knows how to program in Python right?

[image]

Comment: You’re mostly right. But there’s also a tinge of sarcasm in the response.

Comment: so, translate into English sentence, do you know what is the suitable sentence for it?

Comment: 'How far will she go in the future?' I'm not sure. I leave that for others to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

不 = not

得 = able to

了 = end --> be contained

> [不得了](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/9780) (can't be contained): desperately serious; disastrous; extremely; exceedingly

Example:

乱堆的木材一着火就不得了 = Once the messily piled up timber caught fire, it (can't be contained) will be disastrous

他的快球这么强，再学会曲线球 就不得了 = His fastball is so strong if he learned curveball he will be (can't be contained) unstoppable

> 以后还得了? (in the future, how can he still be contained?) is a rhetorical question. It actually means 以后会不得了 (he can't be contained in the future). In other words, 'he will be extremely (outstanding/ extraordinary/ unstoppable) in the future'

> Rhetorical question: "How can he still be stoppable (containable) in the future?"

> Actual statement: "He will be unstoppable (uncontainable) in the future"

I would translate '以后还得了?' as "How extraordinary will he be in the future?".  Meaning:  "he will be great in the future"

Comment: YES! This is what I want. (outstanding/ extraordinary/ unstoppable) Great explain!

Answer (score 3):

L Paker is correct on there is "the sarcasm in the response".

Translating the full response into English:

Too late now. She shall be taught to program Python before even start learning words, then her mother-language would be Programming, and there should have no limit to her potential to be the greatest in the future!

Hidden message: How ridiculous it is to push such a young kid to learn such a difficult task.

Answer (score 2):

Most of time, the phrase 以后还得了 is often used for ***negative connotations***.  It's along the line of (我们不应该放任不管，不然)以后还得了.

It implies that we should do something/take some measures to stop it developing or it would grow to the degree of being big/serious later.

But in some specific context, it can imply positive, so we need to look into the specific context to translate.

P. S.  I can't see the image OP attached, so I don't know the context.

Comment: It's a conversation about her daughter should learn python after she can reads. Do you want me to list out those word?

Comment: it is a picture of an online discussion thread. A:「我女儿刚刚会走路，我是否该在她会识字后立马教她Python?」B:「太晚了，还未识字就该学，这样她人生中的母语就成了Python, 以后还得了？ 」

Comment: And there is a joke; 1. 普通小孩都是:「爸爸，如果我考到满分，能不能给我买个玩具？」 2. Python 小孩: [if my score == 100: ] [my_toys.append("新玩具")]

Comment: @kit After seeing the quote Tang Ho put, it's an irony or a sarcasm.

Comment: Yes, B is mocking A's eagerness to push education on his daughter who is obviously too young for it

Comment: @TangHo Chinese parent most likely are these type...

Comment: @dan but if her daughter using the python method, she'll definitely get a toy IF she score 100. (*if her father willing to follow the instruction) *laughing facepalm